# HTML button which can display webpage cookies

Tags: html, button, cookies

I am trying to make an HTML button, which when pressed can display the current webpage's cookies.

I know how to read/directly show the cookie via

```
<script>javascript:alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

I am trying to find a way to do this through a button.

Comment: describe your problem fully..

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="alert(document.cookie)">Cookies</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onclick="showCookie()">Show cookies</button>

<script>
    function showCookie()
    {
        alert(document.cookie);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'onClick' property of the button to attach an event and get cookies.

```html
<button onClick="alert(document.cookie)">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a javascript function:

```
<script> function showCookie() {alert(document.cookie);}</script>
```

and use the onClick event on HTML button element:

```
<button onClick="showCookie()">Click me</button>
```